# Is it possible to graph this?

Tags: data-visualization

Is it possible to graph this?  I tried doing it on a calculator but didn't have any success.  If someone can and post the graph I would greatly appreciate it.

$$\frac{1}{\bar{m}_{T}}\sqrt{\frac{1}{12} \sum_{h=T-11}^{T} (m_{h} - \bar{m}_{T})^2}.$$

If the equation is hard to read, it is just the standard deviation of 12 observations $(m_{h})$, $h=T-11, T-10, \ldots, T$, over the mean of the same 12 observations. The standard deviation is the population standard deviation and the mean $\bar{m}_{T}$ is simple average.

Comment: It is possible to write well-formed $\LaTeX$ on this site.  Please rewrite so that you're sure you know what should be written - otherwise it's guesswork for answerers.

Comment: I dont know latex? This was written in equation editor in office. i added the "bar" because that didnt translate.

Comment: I'm not yet very familiar with CV myself, but there may be a FAQ around here that points to LaTeX formatting (cue: moderators :)).  Another more immediately useful option is to post an image of the formuala you intend - you can do a printscreen & save the image to a jpg, then post into your question.

Comment: @Iterator Links to the TeX formatting help appear on the right of the textbox when asking a question.

Comment: What, precisely, do you mean by "graph this"?  The expression depends on 12 variables!

Comment: @whuber: Can you provide a direct link?  I looked at the FAQs that appear when asking a question, but couldn't find where to direct the OP.  Thanks!

Comment: @Iterator Start [asking a question](http://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/ask).  Put the cursor in the question textbox. Look at the right.  There are two links to TeX help at the bottom.

Comment: @whuber: Thanks for reformatting.  JM: what do you intend to graph?  As whuber says, it is a lot of variables.

Comment: @whuber: Aha!  I didn't click in the textbox. Nice bit of interface magic there. :)

Comment: @JM: But it has 12 values of `h` - hence the 12 variables that whuber mentioned.

Comment: @whuber@Iterator The reason I am trying to calculate this is after using this a bunch of times I have started to notice a pattern that resembles something like a higher order polynomial equation might look like when graphed. I know there are a lot of variables going on.

Comment: IMO you are asking a bad question; the core idea behind visualization is to see something, not just to make a picture -- i.e. what is your aim here? Check the behavior for some specific case? Compare to some other statistic?

Comment: Check the behavior as these variables move around.

Comment: Note to whoever edited my $\LaTeX$ comment (1st one): Thanks!  I am amused I forgot the correct coding.  The reminder is helpful.

Comment: @JM IF you want to know what happens when your variables 'move around', can you enlighten us how you expect them to move around? Do these come from (e.g.) a normal distribution? Are they limited to a certain region? etc. Once you know that: generate (repeatedly) 12 observations and calculate your statistic of interest. If you do this 10000 times, you can then look at the histogram (or even a smoothed version) of these 10000 values for the statistic. Is this what you want?

Answer (score 5):

I have no idea if this is what the poster is looking for, but I was curious so started exploring and thought I'd share.  Using more traditional notation, let $X_1, ..., X_{n}$ be i.i.d. with $X_i \sim N(\mu, \sigma^2)$.  Then $E(\bar X | X_1)$ is a linear function of $X_1$ and $E(\sum(X_i-\bar X)^2/n | X_1)$ is a quadratic function of $X_1$; so if the mean is always positive, the expected value of the variance/mean is quadratic also.  Not too hard to check if you're patient with your algebra; I'm not, so will demonstrate by simulation. Whether the sd/mean is quadratic or not is left to the reader, who is again hopefully more patient with algebra than I.

An intuitive explanation is that when one of the random variables is above or below the true mean, the sample mean is also more likely to be above or below the true mean.  But the sample standard deviation is more likely to be large when one of the random variables is far from the true mean (either above or below) and more likely to be small when it's near the true mean.

[image: Output of simulation]

```
set.seed(5)
N <- 1000
n <- 12

d <- matrix(rnorm(n*N,mean=8),ncol=n)
m <- rowMeans(d)
s <- apply(d, 1, sd)

par(mfrow=c(1,3))
plot(d[,1],m, col="#88888888", xlab=expression(m[1]), ylab="mean", main="mean")
lines(lowess(d[,1], m))
plot(d[,1],s, col="#88888888", xlab=expression(m[1]), ylab="sd", main="sd")
lines(lowess(d[,1], s))
plot(d[,1],s/m, col="#88888888", xlab=expression(m[1]), ylab="sd/mean", main="sd/mean")
lines(lowess(d[,1], s/m))
```

Answer (score 5):

Typically, when data are serially indexed like this, they form a series (usually a time series): **the formula asks for the [coefficient of variation](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Coefficient_of_variation) within a twelve-period moving window** (as if the data were monthly and the moving window were a year, for instance).  If this is the case, graphing takes two steps:

1. For each index $T$ of 12 or greater, compute the CV for the window spanning indexes $T-11$ through $T$.  This gives a derived series $CV_T$, also indexed by $T$, for all $T \ge 12$.
2. Plot the pairs $(T, CV_T)$.

For example, the data (shown for $T=1, 2, \ldots, 100$) might look like

[image: Dot plot of data]

and the derived series--the "moving CV"--would then look like

[image: Moving CV as a line plot]